# connection refused error with LDAP?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ldap

I am trying to run following program:

```
package jndi;

import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;


public class LDAPRead {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:389/o=jaydeetechnology");
        try{
            System.out.println("creating initial directory context");
            DirContext ctx = (DirContext) new InitialContext(env);
            System.out.println("search for john hunt");
            Attributes attrs = ctx.getAttributes("cn=John Hunt , ou=JayDeeTechnology");
            System.out.println("find the surname and print it");
            System.out.println("sn: "+attrs.get("sn").get());
            ctx.close();
        }catch(NamingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

but I am getting 'Connection refused' error. Could any one please help me if I am missing something?

```
creating initial directory context
javax.naming.CommunicationException: localhost:389 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:222)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.<init>(LdapClient.java:130)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getInstance(LdapClient.java:1592)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2664)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:305)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:187)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:205)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:148)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:78)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:235)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.initializeDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:318)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:348)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.internalInit(InitialContext.java:286)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:211)
    at jndi.LDAPRead.main(LDAPRead.java:31)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:245)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:232)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:377)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:539)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:488)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:385)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:199)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.createSocket(Connection.java:364)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:199)
    ... 14 more
```

I am using RSA 8.0

Comment: Are you sure the data is correct and enough? Have you tried connecting to that ldap using something like Apache Directory Studio's LDAP Browser?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ops/faq.html#2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the Adobe LDAP Troubleshooting pages](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/195/tn_19576.html):

```
Error: javax.naming.CommunicationException: [server]:[port] [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]

Cause: The port name you have specified for the LDAP/AD server is incorrect.
```

I'd say your using the wrong hostname, the wrong port number, or haven't started you LDAP installation on that server yet.

Try looking in the LDAP server's logs, perhaps you can learn a bit more from there.

Answer (score 0):

'Connection refused' has the same meaning here as everywhere else. Nothing was listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to. Either the service hadn't started or you got the IP or port wrong.